# Showing $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} s_n = + \infty$ is in the set of subsequential limits of $\{s_n\} \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

> Let $E$ be the set of subsequential limits of $\{s_n\} \in \mathbb R$. If $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} s_n = +\infty$, then $E$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb R$, so given any $N \in \mathbb R$, there's some $\{s_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $\color{green}{\text{something $\ge N.$}}$ So for any $\epsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many elements of $\{s_{n_k}\}$ which are $\ge N - \epsilon.$ Now fix some $\epsilon$ and let $M = N - \epsilon$. So, given any $M \in \mathbb R$, there are infinitely many elements $\{s_n\}$ that are $\ge M$ meaning there's some subsequence that diverges to $+\infty$ and so $+\infty \in E.$

If $E$ is not bounded above, then some $\{s_{n_j}\}$ diverges to $+\infty$ meaning $+\infty \in E$. Isn't that enough? Why do we need the part of the proof that follows the $\color{green}{\text{part in green}}$ of the quote above?

[Given definition of subsequential limits](https://ibb.co/D1nYNWq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is perfecty right: Bounded above means
$$
\exists M>0 \forall n:  x_n \le M
$$
and so "not bounded above" means
$$
\forall M>0 \exists n: x_n > M
$$
Which means, that you can let $M=1$, find $n\ge 1$ such that $x_n > 1$.
Then you let $M= x_n+1$ and you know that there exists $k$ with $x_k> x_n+1$.
The point is: if there were no $k>n$ with this property, then all larger values were taken on indices $1..n$ - and the sequence hence bounded. That means that you can assume w.r.o.g. that $k>n$. Iterating you obtain an increasing subsequence that tents to $+\infty$.

Comment: right from the get-go, the proof says there exists $\{s_{n_k}\}$ s.t.  $\{s_{n_k}\} \to +\infty$ where $M = N$. Why do we need to build another such subsequence?

Comment: I believe that we do not need that part. Something went wrong.